VBA ADO transaction detailed error instead of generic
I have a problem with ADO transaction. I would like to catch error that is thrown within db, not generic one.
If I remove transaction and execute command then I am able to get it in VBA using err.description. Something like "***** [example], Line 116. Error Number 2627: Violation of[...]
But If only I will wrap command within transaction I get just "The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction."
I need to get internal error in vba and keep command within transaction.
Sub test()
    On error goto errhandler
    Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    dbConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 15 
    dbConnection.CursorLocation = adUseServer 'adUseClient
    connectionString = GetConnectionString(ConnectionTypes.ADO)
    dbConnection.Open connectionString

    dbConnection.BeginTrans

        Dim exampleCMD As ADODB.Command
        Set exampleCMD = New ADODB.Command
            exampleCMD.ActiveConnection = dbConnection
            exampleCMD.CommandTimeout = MAX_TIMEOUT
            exampleCMD.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
            exampleCMD.CommandText = "example procedure"

        With exampleCMD 
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ReportingDateId", adInteger, adParamInput, 4,     reportingDateID)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@UserName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Null)
        End With
        
        exampleCMD Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
        dbConnection.CommitTrans
errhandler:
     debug.print err.description
     dbConnection.rollback
End sub


Solution one: stop trying to commit a transaction that cannot be committed. Solution two: examine the entire Errors collection and not just the latest error.
